# What is the different between alloc::sync::Arc and std::sync::Arc?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use Arc in my code, but as i read the document, there is 2 places Arc is defined: std crate and alloc crate. So, what is the different between alloc::sync::Arc and std::sync::Arc?

Comment: `alloc` is library which contains all non specific to operating system but still allocating code. Basically, std internally split into 3 parts: core (which can be used everywhere but not allocates), alloc (which contains allocating types and uses core) and std which contains OS specific types like files or mutexes.

Comment: Note that `[src]` link for `std::sync::Arc` actually points into `alloc` source - https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#225-228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `alloc` crate [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/index.html):

> This library provides smart pointers and collections for managing heap-allocated values.
>
> This library, like libcore, normally doesn’t need to be used directly since **its contents are re-exported in the `std` crate**. Crates that use the `#![no_std]` attribute however will typically not depend on std, so they’d use this crate instead.

So there's no difference between `std::sync::Arc` and `alloc::sync::Arc`.

`alloc` also provides `Box`, `Vec`, `String`, the `collections` module, and basically anything in the standard library that requires allocations (hence `alloc`) but not an underlying OS (filesystem, networking, etc). `alloc` is there if you want to write bare-metal (unhosted) software that still gets to use the nice standard library data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The `core` and `alloc` crates exist if you’re writing a kernel or some other low-level piece of software and still need to use those APIs. Unless you’re writing something that is low-level enough to declare `#![no_std]`, there’s no advantage to using `alloc` over `std` since the structures are identical.